# Python3: Looking for alternatives to gevent and pylibmc/python-memcached

Tags: python, python-3.x, gevent, python-memcached

So, I have decided to write my next project with python3, why? Due to the plan for Ubuntu to gradually drop all Python2 support within the next year and only support Python3. (Starting with Ubuntu 13.04)

gevent and the memcached modules aren't officially ported to Python3.

What are some alternatives, already officially ported to Python3, for gevent and pylibmc or python-memcached?

Answer (score 4):

[Circuits](https://bitbucket.org/prologic/circuits/) has now support for Python 3, try it it is great.

Comment: +1 I looked into it. Not deeply tho. I will try rolling with this and report findings :)

Answer (score 1):

for memcached you probably know alternative: redis+python3

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: it's partial, but answer 1/2 of question about memcached

Comment: Thanks, alternatives are important to be pointed out. However, in my case, I cannot use redis.

Answer (score 0):

I am stuck in the same point.

Its core is `greenlet 0.4.0`, which is available in python 3, but not the full libraries (`gevent`, `evenlet` or `concurrence`).

There are some attempts to migrate it, but with no luck.

You can check packages availability in this website: http://py3ksupport.appspot.com/pypi/greenlet

If I find any alternative I would let you know.

Comment: py3ksupport no longer exists :(

Answer (score 0):

[pymemcache](https://github.com/pinterest/pymemcache) : A comprehensive, fast, pure-Python memcached client.

Comparison with other clients

> pylibmc
>
> The pylibmc library is a wrapper around libmemcached, implemented in
>   C. It is fast, implements consistent hashing, the full memcached
>   protocol and timeouts. It does not provide access to the "noreply"
>   flag. It also isn't pure Python, so using it with libraries like
>   gevent is out of the question, and its dependency on libmemcached
>   poses challenges (e.g., it must be built against the same version of
>   libmemcached that it will use at runtime).
>
> Python-memcache
>
> The python-memcache library implements the entire memcached text
>   protocol, has a single timeout for all socket calls and has a flexible
>   approach to serialization and deserialization. It is also written
>   entirely in Python, so it works well with libraries like gevent.
>   However, it is tied to using thread locals, doesn't implement
>   "noreply", can't treat errors as cache misses and is slower than both
>   pylibmc and pymemcache. It is also tied to a specific method for
>   handling clusters of memcached servers.